Dash.js fetches .m4s files when setting video.currentTime and results in errors. Errors when setting video.currentTime in dash.js
Basically, I need to start playing my .mpd file from a given duration using dash.js
I am able to play my .mpd file properly from start to end using dash.js in the browser. But when I want to play it from a specific duration specified in seconds, it requests a few incorrect non-existing .m4s files and results in a 404 error from the server. Below is the JS code -

var video = document.getElementById('video-' + layerId);
var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
player.initialize(video, videoUrl, true);
player.on(dashjs.MediaPlayer.events.STREAM_INITIALIZED, function() {
    video.currentTime = 88; // 
});

Error in console -
XHRLoader.js:102 - GET http://localhost:5000/videos/m4d/video_dash33.m4s 404 (NOT FOUND)
XHRLoader.js:102 - GET http://localhost:5000/videos/m4d/video_dash34.m4s 404 (NOT FOUND)
XHRLoader.js:102 - GET http://localhost:5000/videos/m4d/video_dash35.m4s 404 (NOT FOUND)
Suppose I comment on my 2nd last line, // video.currentTime = 88; Then the whole video plays properly from start to end. But I need the video to start from a specific time say - 88 secs. How can I do it?

The error in my case was in the mpd file created by mp4box. It had an incorrect duration of SegmentTemplate=4000. Because of the incorrect duration, it was calculating non-existent .m4s chunks which led to 404 error from the server.
Solution: 
Setting the duration in SegmentTemplate to 128000 corrected the whole thing in my case.

To check the duration of .m4s file, you can upload your file on this website.
You can check this git issue for more info.


I think only YOU could have found that magic number of 128000. Glad it's solved. I was going to suggest (in past) that the fastest way to solve this was to just use an input MP4 video that has a keyframe at every 4 secs in order to segment as you wanted. Just saying if such a way is useful for a future project (ie: prepare the MP4 for the intended task whether... Reverse play? Frame-by-frame stepping? Segmented every N seconds? etc)

@VC.One that magic number was suggested by a developer from DASH.js itself. Thanks for you efforts in solving the problem.

Does it work if you listen for a first PLAYBACK_TIME_UPDATED, instead of STREAM_INITIALIZED?
I suspect the seekable amount (or duration?) is not known until the first PLAYBACK_TIME_UPDATED.
Try it as:
var video = document.getElementById('video-' + layerId);
var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
player.initialize(video, videoUrl, true);

var is_first_play = true; //## to turn the custom seek on/off

player.on(dashjs.MediaPlayer.events.PLAYBACK_TIME_UPDATED, function() 
{
    if( is_first_play == true )
    {
        video.currentTime = 88; //## test custom seeking on first time update
        is_first_play = false; //## turn off this seek on future (same) Event triggers
    }   
});


Please check this github thread and tell if i can play the video using seek function without modifying my .mpd file - https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/4523#issuecomment-2199756501

Your question details are not making sense... (1) Does a file called video_dash33.m4s exist inside a folder called /mpd/ when you seek to time 88? It is strange that it associates that time with a file that does not exist. (2) What is the duration of one m4s file? Check file using MediaInfo online. Confirm if 2 files have different durations. Maybe calculate the segments needed for a time like 88. Any idea why it thinks segment 33 represents the video's 88th second? (3) What is MP4 box doing? Are you generating the M4S at same time as you play them?


video_dash33.m4s doesn't exist



your mentioned website doesn't show any info on duration of my .m4s file. 3) MP4box is incorrectly converting my mp4 video in mpd file. It incorrectly calculates duration in the mpd file.

